# Unión (rbind) de bases de datos en R, con diferente número de columnas

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio, union

Tengo dos bases que no tienen el mismo número de variables (columnas) pero que todas las variables que contiene la base de menor tamaño son iguales a los de la base grande. Deseo poder unir estas bases una debajo de otra y que las variables que le faltan a la base pequeña se complete con ceros o valores `NA`
Lo intenté con la función o código `rbind` pero para esta las bases deben contar con el mismo # de variables (columnas) y mi deseo es pegar una base debajo de otra y rellenar las columnas faltantes con ceros dado que se busca optimizar este proceso para la unión de múltiples bases.

Comment: Jeison Valencia, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal.

Comment: Jeison aunque tu pregunta es comprensible  trata de dejar un ejemplo mínimo reproducible de lo que has intentado hacer hasta el momento. Puedes checar a lo que me refiero en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo con distintos paquetes y en R base. Usando la data pre cargada en R `iris`, creamos dos conjuntos de datos `df1` con todas la columnas de `iris` y orto solo con las primeras tres.

```
df1<- head(iris)#Toma las primeras 10 filas
df2<- tail(iris)[,1:3] #3 primera columnas y 10 ultimas filas
df1
df2

#Usando dplyr
dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)

#Con data.table
data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)

#Usando R base
#Primero creamos las columnas faltantes en df2 llenas de NA
df2[names(df1)[which(!names(df1)%in%names(df2))]] <- NA
rbind(df1, df2)
```

Nota: se usa `::` para llamar una función de una librería sin haberla cargado, puedes omitir `dplyr::` y `data.table::` si previamente las cargas usando `library()`.